# ResourceDictionary with MVVM and Prism

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism, resourcedictionary

I have set up a Prism project with one module. In the module I have defined some views. I want to use a ResourceDictionary to style UI elements.

However...if I include the following code in the View1.xaml
i get the following error

> Warning   1   The designer does not support loading dictionaries that mix 'ResourceDictionary' items without a key and other items in the same collection. Please ensure that the 'Resources' property does not contain 'ResourceDictionary' items without a key, or that the 'ResourceDictionary' item is the only element in the collection.

Here is the code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>                
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If I include the code in the App.xaml file the style looks applied in the designer, but when I run the project i get the following error:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key

Do you have any useful advices how to use ResourceDictionary styles with Prism and MVVM?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a ressource without key in the dictionary?

Comment: No...all the resources have a key.

However...i now added the ResourceDictionary inside the Grid..like Grid.Resources and the thing works..but I don't understand why it does not allow this in the Usercontrol.Resources

Comment: Moving it from UserControl.Resources to Grid.Resources also worked for me, though I too have no idea why.

Comment: Ensure that each resource in your ResourceDictionary.xaml has a x:key or a x:Name attribute and check that those names or keys only contains letters, decimal digits and _

Comment: Furthermore try to check for key uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this guy here had a similar problem:
http://blog.caraulean.com/2011/09/13/how-to-make-caliburn-micro-and-silverlight-resources-in-mergeddictionaries-play-nicely-together/
Have a check

Comment: Link no longer valid :-(